# How do you trap an Endermite without Boats or Minecarts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to build an enderman farm but on the server I am playing on boats and minecarts despawn. How can I trap an Endermite with the enderman being able to see it without minecarts or boats?

Comment: What server are you playing on? There are potentially other difficulties which could arise with solutions depending on the server.

Comment: @Topcode Do you want the name of the server or more information about the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the endermite on a solid block, surround it with chains (orientation doesn't seem to matter) and place a solid block above the endermite to prevent it from jumping over the chains.
[image: caged endermite]

The general solution is probably to exploit the path finding mechanics. The common double carpet trick unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: This method works for some non-cubed-shaped object, I think fences and such works too.